# How to check php API in browser by passing values in url if I'm using POST method in API?

Tags: php, mysql, api, updating

This API working fine when I'm testing on Postman but when I'm trying to check 
in browser by passing id in url it showing error.
*http://192.168.43.88/mydatabase/delete.php?id=1*
when I use GET method then then my able to pass value in url  but why m getting error in case of POST method.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if($id == '') {
        echo 'please provide required value';
    } else {
        require_once('connection.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM circle_detail WHERE id='$id' AND deleted='0' ";
        $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));
        if(isset($check)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE  circle_detail SET deleted='1' WHERE id='$id'";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo 'marked as deleted';
            } else {
                echo 'oops! Please try again!';
            } 
        } else { 
            echo 'not found';
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: You should post the error that you are seeing. 
Also, how are you simulating a POST in a browser? Just typing the URL into the address bar will be a GET only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use GET and POST you 
remove

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { }
```

and use

> $_REQUEST['id']

instead of $_POST

Comment: Can we use volley without using REQUEST_METHOD in android ?

Comment: sorry, i dont know what volley is.

Comment: volley is an android http libray, well just use POST as a REQUEST_METHOD. it will cover all areas of data transfer you may need to send. And your data wont get logged with the url in the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the POST request method but passing the variable in as a GET parameter then you need to change the following code:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

To be

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

This way when it is a POST request it'll still look for the get parameter. Where as it is currently looking for a POST variable called id

Answer (score 0):

You can not call POST Method API from the browser for that you should use "Postman". 
`Postman` is the complete toolchain for API developers,

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)

or use Rest Client

[Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)